# lnd fails to connect to the network

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, tor

Ubuntu 22.04
lnd 0.15.3-beta
tor 0.4.6.10

When I run `lnd`, it never connects to the network. The output contains the line:

```
[ERR] SRVR: Unable to retrieve initial bootstrap peers: no addresses found
```

`tor.log` contains lots of lines like these:

```
We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $B558F456FB410E6CDF3D33AC5EB5305D66DA8B19~bauruine [hu1YYHdLr/hlWFXBWKMxQnaQbHIK4+9aotdZtYoZ2c4] at 23.137.251.61. Retrying on a new circuit.
Tried for 130 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:53. Giving up.
```

The messages in the `tor.log` file only show up when lnd is running.

lnd.conf

```
bitcoin.active=true
bitcoin.mainnet=true
bitcoin.node=bitcoind
bitcoin.minhtlc=1
bitcoin.feerate=1
bitcoin.basefee=1000
bitcoin.defaultchanconfs=2

bitcoind.rpchost=192.168.1.38:8901
bitcoind.zmqpubrawblock=tcp://192.168.1.38:28332
bitcoind.zmqpubrawtx=tcp://192.168.1.38:28333
bitcoind.rpcuser=username
bitcoind.rpcpass=password

tor.active=true
tor.v3=true
tor.socks=127.0.0.1:9050
tor.control=127.0.0.1:9051
tor.streamisolation=true

listen=0.0.0.0:9735
rpclisten=0.0.0.0:10009
debuglevel=debug

sync-freelist=1
stagger-initial-reconnect=1
ignore-historical-gossip-filters=1
db.bolt.auto-compact=1
max-channel-fee-allocation=1.0
maxpendingchannels=10
protocol.wumbo-channels=true
minchansize=5000000
max-cltv-expiry=5000

routerrpc.apriorihopprob=0.5
routerrpc.aprioriweight=0.75
routerrpc.attemptcost=10
routerrpc.attemptcostppm=10
routerrpc.minrtprob=0.005
routerrpc.penaltyhalflife=6h0m0s

tlsautorefresh=true
tlsdisableautofill=true
```

torrc

```
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
CookieAuthFile /var/lib/tor/control_auth_cookie
DataDirectoryGroupReadable 1
CacheDirectoryGroupReadable 1
Log notice file /var/log/tor/tor.log
```

It seems like the problem would have something to do with `lnd` because I stop getting the `tor.log` error messages when I shut down `lnd`. Also, I am able to reach the outside Internet by using `torsocks`.

What do I have to change to get this working?

Comment: Are you able to manually connect to a node with `lncli connect <pubkey>@<address>:<port>`? ACINQ node: `03864ef025fde8fb587d989186ce6a4a186895ee44a926bfc370e2c366597a3f8f@of7husrflx7sforh3fw6yqlpwstee3wg5imvvmkp4bz6rbjxtg5nljad.onion:9735`

Comment: No. It returns an empty JSON object.

Comment: Empty JSON is expected result. Run `lncli listpeers` after running the above command. Also check the terminal running `lnd`. Example (testnet): https://pastebin.com/raw/KGUjjGEk

Comment: The result contains an array that has one peer in it.

Comment: And I am seeing a lot of activity in my terminal. Also, running `lncli getnetworkinfo` is showing actual numbers instead of all zeros, and the numbers are growing as if it is syncing. Are the calls to `connect` and `listpeers` a requirement, or was something configured incorrectly?

Comment: Bootstrapping didn't work, I was just confirming if manual connections to nodes are working. Even I am new LND user experimenting with lot of things so not sure about everything.